# Correctly converting floating point in C++

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point

What would be the correct/recommended way of telling the C++ compiler "only warn me of floating point conversions that I'm not aware of"?

In C, I would enable the warnings related to floating point conversions, and then I would use explicit C-style casts to silence warnings related to the conversions that are under control.

For example, computing `a*a*a - b*b` is quite prone to overflow in single precision floating point, so you might wish to compute it in double precision and only go single precision later:

```
double a = 443620.52;
double b = 874003.01;
float c = (float)(a*a*a - b*b);
```

The above C-style explicit cast would silence the compiler warning about the conversion from `double` to `float`.

Reading C++ documentation about casts, I get to the conclusion that the correct way of doing this in C++ would be as follows:

```
double a = 443620.52;
double b = 874003.01;
float c = static_cast<float>(a*a*a - b*b);
```

But, is this really the correct way of doing this in C++?

I understand the rationale behind the `static_cast` syntax being [ugly on purpose](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#static-cast), so that you avoid casts completely if possible.

Yes, I can omit the explicit cast to float. But then I need to disable compiler warnings telling me of precision loss (or otherwise I'd get a number of irrelevant warnings that would make it difficult to notice really relevant warnings). And if I disable fp-related compiler warnings, I'd lose the possibility of being warned when I'm mistakenly losing precision in other code places.

So, what's the correct approach for floating point conversions in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
float c = static_cast<float>(a*a*a - b*b);
```

is the correct way of explicitly casting to float in C++.  You can also do:

```
float c = (float)(a*a*a - b*b);
```

but using a "C-style" cast like that is bad style because `static_cast` will hide rather fewer errors than C-style.

Alternatively, if you are doing this a lot, you can define a function:

```
inline float flt(double d){return static_cast<float>(d);}
```

and then you can write:

```
float c = flt(a*a*a - b*b);
```

which is even more compact than the original C (and will be optimized away to nothing).

Comment: But the casts from `double` to `float` are frequent in floating point programming. The `static_cast` "ugliness" would be an undeserved punishment IMHO, given that the cast is not only legit, but necessary, and not possible to avoid no matter how good the coding style.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your advice regarding defining a function meets my needs fully, and it's clean C++ coding style.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there are three different ways to avoid the warning:

1. C-style cast
2. `static_cast`
3. Constructor-style cast (e.g. `float c = float(a*a*a-b*b)`)

In the code example below, `c1`, `c2` and `c3` avoid the warnings:

```
int main()
{
  double a = 443620.52;
  double b = 874003.01;

  // These three versions avoid the conversion warnings:
  float c1 = (float)(a*a*a - b*b);
  float c2 = static_cast<float>(a*a*a - b*b);
  float c3 = float(a*a*a - b*b);

  // Only these two give conversion warnings:
  float c4(a*a*a - b*b);
  float c5 = a*a*a - b*b;

  (void)c1; // Just to avoid unused-variable warnings
  (void)c2;
  (void)c3;
  (void)c4;
  (void)c5;
}
```

Only `c4` and `c5` trigger a warning.  [Check the live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72c6d66fb70b6075) to see the results.